# Ethers js adding provider

Tags: dapps, javascript, ethers.js

I have an app I am working on implementing ethers.js. There are two methods I am using to create a wallet: `new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);` and `new ethers.Wallet.createRandom();`

With creating a random wallet, it doesnt seem like you can give it the `provider` like when importing a private key. That is fine, because once you log out and back in at a later time and get the wallet `fromEncryptedJson`, both from the private key import, and the creating a random wallet the `provider` is now `undefined`

Initially `wallet.provider` from the import account is there, but after logging out (encrypting the wallet) and then logging back in, after getting the wallet from encryption, `provider` is not defined. I need the provider at later times in the app, for instance using the method `wallet.getTransactionCount();`, this uses the provider, but it is undefined after logging back in. And if I do `wallet.provider = provider` I cant re-assign this value as it says its read only.

So is there a way to set the provider when you un-encrypt the wallet?

Answer (score 1):

**** EDIT ****

Figured it out.

```
ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedJson(encryptedWallet, passphrase).then((myWallet) => {
    const loggedInWallet = myWallet.connect(provider);
    // loggedInWallet will now have provider added
}
```

---

Currently the only solve I have been able to get to work is kinda hacky. Object assign does not seem to copy all the key pairs for some reason. I used `Object.create` and passed in the wallet once un-encrypted.

```
const LoggedInWallet = Object.create(walletFromUnencryption);
LoggedInWallet.__proto__ = myWallet.__proto__;
LoggedInWallet._ethersType = myWallet._ethersType;
LoggedInWallet.provider = provider;
LoggedInWallet.signingKey = myWallet.signingKey;
```

This gave me a wallet with the needed data for use while user is logged in.

Not ideal it would seem. I would think when un-encrypting the wallet you could do something like:

```
ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedJson(encryptedWallet, passphrase, provider).then((walletFromUnencryption) =>
```

adding provider as an option passing in, but doesnt seem like thats possible. So I will resort to what I have working for now till I can find the solution how to get the provider when un-encrypting the wallet